# Using DHTML and JavaScript to move object

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am stuck.  I am a student learning JavaScript and this assignment is kicking my arse...Why?  Because there is no point of text/tutorials etc to help.  Was told to study the code and make it move.  Originally it moved left to right ... was able to change it and have it move from top to bottom.  Where I am stuck is not I have to move it move diagonally across the page.  I cannot find anything ... please help.  Not asking to do it but to give a hint or point in direction of tutorial...

Here is the code I have now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DHTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--

        var row = 0;

        function moveBoatRight()
       {  //function moves boat towards the right shore     

            document.getElementById("Man").style.top=100+(row*12);  //This accesses the graphic on the page and moves its position

            if (row < 20)
            {
                 row++;  //only need 20 iterations to make it across the river
                window.setTimeout("moveBoatRight();",130);  //Recursive function that gives a slight delay in time to look more fulid
            } 

       }//end of moveBoatRight Function

     //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFCE" >
                <h1><strong>Using DHTML</strong></h1>

                    <div id="Man" style="position:relative; left:100px; top:100px; visibility:visible; y-index:1; width: 100px; height: 103px;"><img border="0" src="arrowDown.png" width="95" height="103"></div> 
    </div>

    <form>
        <input type="button" id="sbutton" value="submit" onClick="moveBoatRight();">
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: this sounds a lot like a "do my homework" question... But anyway: diagonally means sideways and vertically. That should help you, i guess.

Comment: By the way: welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute or two and take the [tour].

Comment: Actually if you read the last sentence I am asking to pointed in the right direction not for someone to do my homework.  And no diagonally does not mean sideways or vertically.  Vertically means up and down.  Horizontal means sideways.  Diagonal means from top left to bottom right or from top right to bottom left.

DHTML code from 2004 (as this is the only reference I could find) is as follows and does not incorporate JavaScript.

function moveObject(ObjectID,x,y) {
var object = document.getElementById(objectID);
object.style.left = x+'px';
object.style.top = y + 'px';

Comment: He said sideways AND vertically. If you know how to make it go up and down and you know how to make it go left and right, you have ecerything you need. you have to do the movements at the same time

Comment: Thanks chilli ... When I say that teacher said figure it out, I really meant that.  The instructions were study the code and figure it out.  So in order to moved it up and down I changed the z-index to y-index, changed my block from .left to .top, and changed position to relative.

I am getting stuck at how to make them work together.  Would I write y-index:1 and z-index-1 to make the move?  Do I leave the position absolute or relative?  I have been trying variations but no luck and I have watched several tutorials on DHTML and movement but nothing combines both. Just need direction.

Comment: y-index and x-index don't exist. z-index is completely unrelated to your problem, But you should check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for more info about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the trick for you:

```
function moveBoatdiagonally() { 

        document.getElementById("Man").style.top=100+(row*12);  //This accesses the graphic on the page and moves its position
        document.getElementById("Man").style.left=100+(row*12);  //This accesses the graphic on the page and moves its position

        if (row < 20) {
             row++;  //only need 20 iterations to make it across the river
            window.setTimeout("moveBoatRight();",130);  //Recursive function that gives a slight delay in time to look more fulid
        } 

   }
```

As you can see, in every iteration of the loop, you move your "boat" firts in y, then in x direction. The result will look like a diagonal direction.

You can of course switch them if you prefer for some reasons.

The backgroud is that you have a rectangular grid of pixels, and a very fast way of actually moving the object. You are not able to notice that it is actually two distinct moves.

Comment: Thank you Burki.  That actually makes total sense.  I just finished reading a tutorial on it and mentioned the pixels aspect of the movement and that z-index needs to be a positive integer.  And now seeing it all pops together.

Another quick question....why use DHTML and JavaScript together...I thought DHTML went the wayside a back before 2010?

Comment: @JasonNorthcutt the preferred way for thank yous around here are upvotes, maybe even accepted answers ;-)
For your other question: a simple answer is you need something to start learning. Then, build up your knowledge step by step. BTW: i started programming long before that, so some people might even call that modernistic stuff ;-) Oh, and do take the [tour], it is really quite informative.

Comment: as he is a new user he does not have enough reputation to upvote. but you can have mine :)

Comment: Thank you to both.  I am still learning ... it does not help that the class assignments are watch a youtube video and create, but I have learned a lot so far...and it does not help I work full time and 40 years old.  LOL....

But seriously you both have been a great help!